# Running ruby scripts in parallel

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing

Let's say I've got two ruby scripts - a.rb and b.rb. Both are web-scrapers used for different pages. They can work for many, many hours and I would like to run them simultaneously. In order to do that I've tried to run them by third script using 'promise' gem with the following code:

```
def method_1
require 'path to my file\a'
end
def method_2
require 'path to my file\b'
end
require 'future'
x=future{method_1}
y=future{method_2}
x+y
```

However this solution throws an error(below) and only one script is executed.

```
An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. 
(Errno::ENOTSOCK)
```

I also tried playing with Thread class:

```
def method_one
require 'path to my file\a'
end

def method_two
require 'path to my file\b'
end

x = Thread.new{method_one}
y = Thread.new{method_two}

x.join
y.join
```

And it gives me the same error as for 'promise' gem.

I've also run those scripts in separate shells- then they work at the same time, but the performance is much worse (aprox. about 50% slower).
Is it any way to run them at the same time and keep high performance?

Comment: If you're open to alternative technologies. Go & Goroutines would be amazing in this instance. Ruby isn't the best language for concurrency, so it isn't ideal for scrapers.

Comment: When replacing `require 'path to my file \{a,b}'` with `puts __method__` the *Thread* option works fine for me. This suggests the exception is raised inside the *require* statement.

Comment: @JohanWentholt Could you be more specific what should i do? Because your solution doesn't point to the my files - a.rb or b.rb

Answer (score 0):

You can use [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) for this, here is how you can run both your scripts in parallel:

```rb
require 'concurrent'
# Create future for running script a
future1 = Concurrent::Promises.future do
  require 'path to file\a'
  :result
end
# Create future for running script b
future2 = Concurrent::Promises.future do
  require 'path to file\b'
  :result
end
# Combine both futures to run them in parallel
future = Concurrent::Promises.zip(future1, future1)
# Wait until both scripts are completed
future.value!
```